# Base64 Conversion to Number in DataWeave Returns incorrect value

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have the following in Python that decodes `Yag=` and returns the bytes `b'a\xa8'` and converts to an integer of `25000`

```
import base64

num = base64.b64decode("Yag=")
converted = int.from_bytes(num, byteorder='big')
```

When I use the following DataWeave script it returns `a\ufffd` and `97`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Binaries
var num = fromBase64("Yag=")
var converted = num as Number
---
{
    num: num,
    converted: converted
}
```

The Python block returns the expected result. Am I missing something about DataWeave and how it decodes Base64?

Comment: Please don't use DWL to say DataWeave. It is not a standard term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataWeave returns a correct result. The error comes from the assumption that the binary representation of a number is the same between DataWeave and Python. In general you should not make that assumption between any two different languages.

To avoid that issue you can use the Binaries module function `toHex()` to get an hexadecimal representation of the binary, then use the function `fromHex()` from the Numbers module to convert the hexadecimal string to a Number.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Binaries
var num = fromBase64("Yag=")
var converted = num as Number
---
{
    num: num,
    converted: converted,
    toHex: toHex(num),
    toHexToNumber: dw::core::Numbers::fromHex(toHex(num))
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "num": "a\ufffd",
  "converted": 97,
  "toHex": "61A8",
  "toHexToNumber": 25000
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Do you have recommendations on how to handle negative hex values since we don't have bitwise operators. How do we handle 2s complement?

Comment: Please open new questions for those topics.